# Websocket API bitfinex

Tags: javascript, websocket

Пытаюсь вывести orderbook с помощью вебсокетов bitfinex, но в браузере получаю ошибку

```
    const BOOK = {}
    var ws = new WebSocket("wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2");
    ws.onopen = function(){ 
  BOOK.bids = {}
  BOOK.asks = {}
  BOOK.psnap = {}
  BOOK.mcnt = 0

  // send websocket conf event with checksum flag
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: 'conf', flags: 131072 }))

  // send subscribe to get desired book updates
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: 'subscribe', channel: 'book', pair: 'tBTCUSD', prec: 'P0' }))
}

// handle incoming messages
ws.onmessage = function(msg){
  msg = JSON.parse(msg)
  if (msg.event) return
  if (msg[1] === 'hb') return

  // if msg contains checksum, perform checksum
  if (msg[1] === 'cs') {
    const checksum = msg[2]
    const csdata = []
    const bidsKeys = BOOK.psnap['bids']
    const asksKeys = BOOK.psnap['asks']

    // collect all bids and asks into an array
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      if (bidsKeys[i]) {
        const price = bidsKeys[i]
        const pp = BOOK.bids[price]
        csdata.push(pp.price, pp.amount)
      }
      if (asksKeys[i]) {
        const price = asksKeys[i]
        const pp = BOOK.asks[price]
        csdata.push(pp.price, -pp.amount)
      }
    }

    // create string of array to compare with checksum
    const csStr = csdata.join(':')
    const csCalc = CRC.str(csStr)
    if (csCalc !== checksum) {
      console.error('CHECKSUM FAILED')
      process.exit(-1)
    } else {
      console.log('Checksum: ' + checksum + ' success!')
    }
    return
  }

  // handle book. create book or update/delete price points
  if (BOOK.mcnt === 0) {
    _.each(msg[1], function (pp) {
      pp = { price: pp[0], cnt: pp[1], amount: pp[2] }
      const side = pp.amount >= 0 ? 'bids' : 'asks'
      pp.amount = Math.abs(pp.amount)
      BOOK[side][pp.price] = pp
    })
  } else {
    msg = msg[1]
    const pp = { price: msg[0], cnt: msg[1], amount: msg[2] }

    // if count is zero, then delete price point
    if (!pp.cnt) {
      let found = true

      if (pp.amount > 0) {
        if (BOOK['bids'][pp.price]) {
          delete BOOK['bids'][pp.price]
        } else {
          found = false
        }
      } else if (pp.amount < 0) {
        if (BOOK['asks'][pp.price]) {
          delete BOOK['asks'][pp.price]
        } else {
          found = false
        }
      }

      if (!found) {
        console.error('Book delete failed. Price point not found')
      }
    } else {
      // else update price point
      const side = pp.amount >= 0 ? 'bids' : 'asks'
      pp.amount = Math.abs(pp.amount)
      BOOK[side][pp.price] = pp
    }

    // save price snapshots. Checksum relies on psnaps!
    _.each(['bids', 'asks'], function (side) {
      const sbook = BOOK[side]
      const bprices = Object.keys(sbook)
      const prices = bprices.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (side === 'bids') {
          return +a >= +b ? -1 : 1
        } else {
          return +a <= +b ? -1 : 1
        }
      })
      BOOK.psnap[side] = prices
    })
  }
  BOOK.mcnt++
}

    </script>
```

Ошибка

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (ws_test1.php:22)
```

Comment: Может кто помочь?

Comment: Там же написано - не ожидаемый токен `o` в JSON позиции 1. Скорее всего не может распарсить JSON, посмотри ответ без парсинга: `console.log(msg)`

Comment: @Владислав Вот что выводит в консоль MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "[299,[5527.2,0,1]]", origin: "wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}

Comment: Объект `MessageEvent`. Раз это объект, значит вряд ли его распарсим, но сможем взаимодействовать с его методами и свойствами. Есть же документация: [тык](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/docs/ws-general), там явно написано: `wss.onmessage = (msg) => console.log(msg.data)`

Comment: @Владислав вот что выводит, если тупо вывести msg.data: {"event":"info","version":2,"serverId":"04942d95-5e13-4d9d-856b-0138afa9c97f","platform":{"status":1}}